# cast a `&&*const libc::foreignStruct` to a `&libc::foreignStruct`

Tags: rust, nftables

I'm using [nftnl-rs](https://github.com/mullvad/nftnl-rs) to build a table of nftables rules, with great success. But now I want to know if there is already a table with the same name in the system. I found two functions in nftnl-rs' `nftnl/src/table.rs` that seem to be exactly made for this : [get_tables_nlmsg()](https://github.com/mullvad/nftnl-rs/blob/34a51a0c56f444b70f838389a1cc2236cb962273/nftnl/src/table.rs#L75) and [get_tables_cb()](https://github.com/mullvad/nftnl-rs/blob/34a51a0c56f444b70f838389a1cc2236cb962273/nftnl/src/table.rs#L91). However I was not able to use them successfully.`get_tables_cb()`'s docstring says it was made to process the output of the former, but `get_tables_nlmsg()` returns a `Vec<u8>`, apparently containing the memory address of the created nlmsghdr, whereas `get_tables_cb()` takes an `&nlmsghdr` as an argument.

Specifically, I tried :

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::ffi::CString;
use nftnl{self, nftnl_sys::libc};

fn dump_tables() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error> {
    let mut tables: &mut HashSet<CString> = &mut HashSet::new();
    let mut buffer = nftnl::table::get_tables_nlmsg(0);
    let buffer = buffer.as_ptr() as *const libc::nlmsghdr;

    nftnl::table::get_tables_cb(&&buffer, &mut tables);
    println!("{:?}", tables);
    Ok(())
}
```

rustc complains that it expected an `&nlmsghdr` and got a `&&*const nlmsghdr`, and I was not able to cast the former into the latter. I browsed the source code and the examples without seeing this casting case appearing. Jumping back and forth in the source, I found a part of the Nomicon talking about [opaque structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#representing-opaque-structs) that seems to apply to `nlmsghdr`, but doesn't solve my problem either. In fact I'm a little confused with the function declaration :

```rust
pub fn get_tables_cb(header: &libc::nlmsghdr, tables: &mut HashSet<CString>) -> libc::c_int
```

If `*const libc::nlmsghdr` is a foreign Struct, what on earth can `&libc::nlmsghdr` be ? Could it be that there's a typo somewhere in nftnl-rs' source ?

Comment: Have you tried sending the message generated with `get_tables_nlmsg` over the netfilter socket, and parsing the result using `get_tables_cb`?

Comment: I'll try that. Are you by any chance Ls256 on the Arch Wiki ? I recently copied an article on NanoPi_M1 from said wiki to my user page because they threaten to delete it as out of purpose.

Comment: I am not them, but glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Using Coder-256's suggestion, one can find `mnl::cb_run2()` from the sister package [mnl-rs](https://github.com/mullvad/mnl-rs), that may use `nftnl::tables::get_tables_cb()` as a callback when receiving a netlink packet. Since netlink packets may come multi-packed if the data is too big to fit in one NlMsg, one would probably use it like this :

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use mnl;
use nftnl;

fn dump_tables() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let seq = 0;
    let tables = &mut HashSet::new();
    let mut buffer = nftnl::table::get_tables_nlmsg(seq);
    let socket = mnl::Socket::new(mnl::Bus::Netfilter)?;

    socket.send(&buffer)?;
    // Answer may be multi-packed, loop over what we get.
    loop {
        let chars_written = socket.recv(&mut *buffer)?;
        if chars_written == 0 { break; }
        let message = &buffer[..chars_written];
        match mnl::cb_run2(message, seq, socket.portid(), nftnl::table::get_tables_cb, tables)? {
            mnl::CbResult::Stop => break,
            mnl::CbResult::Ok => ()
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", tables);
    Ok(())
}
```

I must confess I still don't know what `&libc::nlmsghdr` means exactly, how and why one would build one ; I will gladly accept any answer that is able to enlighten that point.